# How to paste parameters in R functions using `substitute` and `eval` to make data.table work like dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, non-standard-evaluation

I have a working R function written as:

```
library(data.table)
mutate_dt = function (.data, ..., by) 
{
    dt = as.data.table(.data)
    substitute(dt[, `:=`(...), by][]) %>% eval()
}
```

However, I could not use this function in other functions. For example:

```
t_f = function(dt,x){
  mutate_dt(dt,a = x)
}

t_f(iris,1)
#> Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()): object 'x' not found
```

Is there any way that I can make it work?

Comment: `eval.parent(substitute(dt[, \`:=\`(...), by][]), 1)`

Comment: @Roland please post an answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that the expression is evaluated in the correct environment. R makes it easy by providing the convenience function `eval.parent`:

```
library(data.table)
mutate_dt = function (.data, ..., by) 
{
  dt = as.data.table(.data)
  eval.parent(substitute(dt[, `:=`(...), by][]))
}

mutate_dt(iris,a = 1)
#works

t_f = function(dt,x){
  mutate_dt(dt,a = x)
}

t_f(iris,2)
#works
```